# Problema ao verificar se usuário já existe antes de cadastrar

Tags: php, mysql

Tô começando agora, e tenho uma dúvida. Eu tinha feito pra cadastrar uma categoria, até aí ok, mas percebi que estava cadastrando mesmo com uma categoria já existente, aí resolvi adicionar uma função pra verificar no banco de dados se o que foi digitado já tem lá, mas não estou conseguindo.

```
<?php
session_start();
$adicionar_categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
include_once("../../config/conexao.php");

//Verifica se a categoria já existe.
    $vcategoria = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categorias(nomeCategoria) LIMIT 1");

//Se o retorno for maior que 0, diz que já existe uma categoria com o mesmo nome.
if(mysql_num_rows($vcategoria) > 0){
    $_SESSION['categoriaErro'] = "Categoria existente.";
    header("Location: ../adicionar_categoria.php");
}else{
$resultCategoria = mysql_query("INSERT INTO categorias(nomeCategoria) VALUES ('$adicionar_categoria')");
}
//echo "Categoria: ".$resultCategoria['nomeCategoria'];

if(empty($resultCategoria)){
    $_SESSION['categoriaErro'] = "Por favor, adicione uma categoria válida.";
    header("Location: ../adicionar_categoria.php");
}else{
    $_SESSION['categoriaSucesso'] = "Categoria adicionada com sucesso.";
    header("Location: ../adicionar_categoria.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua query de busca está errada, deveria ser assim:

```
SELECT * FROM categorias WHERE nomeCategoria = '$adicionar_categoria' LIMIT 1
```

**PORÉM:** o seu código tem **sérios problemas de compatibilidade e segurança**. Sugiro fortemente consultar esta outra pergunta: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/74)

Comment: Pra quem está começando é difícil reescrever mysql pra mysqli, mas obrigado, resolveu ali.